# Array push alters all elements

Tags: javascript

```js
var MyObject = function(x, y) {
  self.x = x;
  self.y = y;
  return self;
}

var myObjects = [];


var f1 = new MyObject(150, 200);
var f2 = new MyObject(250, 250);
var f3 = new MyObject(300, 500);
myObjects.push(f1);
myObjects.push(f2);
myObjects.push(f3);

for (var i = 0; i < myObjects.length; i++) {
  console.log(myObjects[i].x);
}
```

The console logs as 3 times 300, which is the x of the last element. I couldn't figure out how this outcome happens?

Comment: What is `self`? Don’t you mean `this`?

Comment: `self` is going to be `window` probably; you definitely want `this`

Comment: self refers to window object which results in having f1,f2,f3 point to same object, hence it is showing 300 as value of x property on window object

Comment: Some people refer to var self = this; to have it globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, Nothing to do with push. when you are doing `self.x = x` it is updating the global object (as, this in global scope) which is window, and you are returning window. your array contains `[window, window, window]` and each time you are overriding `x` and `y` in window. use `this` instead to create object of your prototype and you don't need to return if you are using `new`;

Answer (score 2):

[`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self):

> The Window.self read-only property returns the window itself, as a WindowProxy. It can be used with dot notation on a window object (that is, window.self) or standalone (self).

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

You can notice the difference of `this` in your example by either using or not using the `new` keyword:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log({
    isThisEqualToWindow: self === this,
    self: self.toString(),
    this: this.toString()
  });
}

new foo();
foo();
```

While `self` always refers to the `window` object, `this` can refer to either the object created by `new` (using the function as a constructor) or the `window` object because of the context for the function invocation.

In regards to your specific example, since you are using the `new` constructor then `this` would refer to the created object and would work as you expect:

```js
var MyObject = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  return this;
}

var myObjects = [];


var f1 = new MyObject(150, 200);
var f2 = new MyObject(250, 250);
var f3 = new MyObject(300, 500);
myObjects.push(f1);
myObjects.push(f2);
myObjects.push(f3);

for (var i = 0; i < myObjects.length; i++) {
  console.log(myObjects[i].x);
}
```

Comment: I guess, we can override `window.self`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do var self = this;